# Run Javascript on a firefox instance externally

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have just started hacking around firefox using vimperator which makes extending so much easier. However it is a bit of a pain whenever I make a small change to a js file in `.vimperator/plugins/` and want them tu run that I have to go to firefox and run `:source <filename>`.

I think this is not very vimperator-specific but I may be approaching this wrong. Ideally what I want is, given a shell, to be able to run arbitrary javascript code on a firefox instance.

Oh and I am using arch linux so the obvious answer i guess would be dbus but google hasn't yielded anything relevant.

EDIT: Maybe I should clarify that I am using emacs and what I want is to make a command like `send-region-to-firefox` which will automatically send the selected text to the firefox instance.

Comment: I think of myself as a between intermediate and advanced ff-addon dev but Im lost here man.

Comment: So I am writing a vimeprator plugin (that is just a js file that runs when ff starts up) on my favourite editor (emacs) and I want a piece of code to take effect on my running firefox instance. Right now, I switch to firefox and run on vimperator `source <fname>`. The first problem with this is it is time consuming, the other is I oftend don't want the entire file to be run each time, just a couple of lines. If I could select them and tell emacs "ok now run those on any firefox instance you find running". I dont think this is vimperator specific though.

Comment: still lost, i might have to be a vimperator user to help you out here, hopefully someone can help you there.